# Swift: Fixed Navigation Bar on transition to another view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue, uicontainerview

I'm Trying to perform a segues with a navigation controller but when a segue is performed it brings in a new navigation bar and instead I want it to work like this

**This is a temporary container view just for representation**

[image: screen shot]

So instead of each view controllers having individual navigation bars why not have one static navigation bar.

Comment: Do you want to hide the navigation bar on which you are navigated?

Comment: Not really I want the root navigation bar to persist on every single segue

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code, You want to hide the navigation bar.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Yeah but this wasn't the desired thing cause I'm trying to copy twitters on-boarding for learning purposes and they have this persistent navigation bar which kind of works for all the other view controllers

Comment: I can't see a navigation bar on any controller @Siddhantnair